# Pull SamAccountName into csv from list of employeeID's

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

```
$user = ForEach ($user in $(get-content C:\Users\desktop\employeeids.csv)) {

    Get-ADUser $user -properties employeeid
}

$users |

Select-object Samaccountname |

export-csv -path C:\users\desktop\usernames.csv
```

I am trying to pull the Samaccountname of a list of employee id's I was given and export those samaccountnames into a csv. This is what I have so far but I keep getting the following error

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '12345' under: 'DC=,DC='.
At line:3 char:5
+     Get-ADUser $user -properties employeeid
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (12345:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentity 
   NotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Managem 
   ent.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Get  
  ADUser
```

Comment: You need to     `import-csv` for a csv not     `get-content`

Comment: I am getting the information in - that isn't the problem.  It is running through every user on the list as it is intended to, but it isn't querying them correctly and finding the samaccountname - as shown in my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = ForEach ($user in $(get-content C:\Users\desktop\employeeids.txt)) {
Get-ADUser $user -properties employeeid
}
$users |
Select-object Samaccountname |
export-csv -path C:\users\desktop\usernames.csv
```

I have changed the original variable to     `$users` instead of     `$user`.
I have also changed the file extension to  a   `.txt` but if it is working for you using a     `.csv` extension should be ok